# Locating automatically my addon original folder

Tags: add-on

I've created a small addon, which wrap a much bigger addon. In the execute code, I want first to get the addon' path, add it to python path, and then import my main class and call its main function:

```
user_preferences = context.user_preferences
addon_prefs = user_preferences.addons[__name__].preferences
addon_root = os.path.abspath(addon_prefs.addon_folder)
sys.path.append(addon_root)
import main_addon
main_addon.main(addon_prefs)
```

As you can see, for now I've let the user to set the addon's path in addon_prefs.addon_folder, but I want to find it automatically. 
Can I get the full path of my wrapper addon (both the wrapper addon and my main addon exist in the same folder), and get the folder from there? 
When I've tried

```
os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

I got the ".../config/blender/2.76/scripts/addons" folder, which isn't the original folder.

Comment: If the code above is in `__init__.py` in its own subfolder of the addons dir, (ie with the folder as a module)  then `os.path.dirname(__file__)` will give you that subfolder, eg "/blender/2.77/scripts/addons/sound_drivers".  Have a look at how some of the folder addons are set up using `__init__.py`